# Extracting strings from a pattern in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

i have a dataframe with a column full of strings as follows:

`1                    Janus Henderson Research Fund Class N
2                              Calvert Equity Fund Class A
3               Invesco Diversified Dividend Fund R5 Class
4                    Prudential Day One 2035 Fund Class R3
5                TETON Convertible Securities Fund Class C
                               ...

24991              BlackRock Asian Dragon Fund,Inc.Class R
24993    MFS Blended Research International Equity Fund...
24994                   ClearBridge Small Cap Fund Class A
24995    Federated Equity Income Fund, Inc. Class A Shares`

im looking to extract the class of each of the rows.
for example row 1,  as class N, row 2 as classA and so on.. some of the rows do not have the word class all together, which i would like to be NA. also some of the rows have the class label before the word class. how do i go about extracting this ? 
any guidance is appreciated

Comment: `re.compile(r'\s[A-Z][0-9]?\s')` I have written this regual expression that is capable of splitting out a space followed by a upper case alphabet followed by a number(which is optional) and another space. This seems to bring out the classes i desire, i do not understand how i can iterate through the rows, and change the values, while inserting NaN or something similar where i do not find a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a parsing function that receive a row and look for the word "Class" and then return whatever is next to it.
This function could use `txt.split('Class')` for example. After you are writing this function, you can use `apply()` (dataframe method) to apply it to every row separately.

Comment: Dear Roim, i have tried this, but some of the rows have their labels before the word class For example row no. 3 is R5 class instead of class R5

Comment: I don't fully understand. You mean the text is something like "A Class" instead of "Class A"?

Comment: exactly, note row no.3 which is `Invesco Diversified Dividend Fund R5 Class`

Comment: Let's separate two problems: how to find a class given a text, and how to iterate through rows. I hope I addressed the second problem using apply method. For parsing, you can regex as you said yourself. Create a function that parse the text as you want it (using regex). If found a class, return string. otherwise return nan.

Comment: thank you roin, while using the apply, do i need to nest it in a for loop ? or how do i go about it ? do i write a definition and then`df['column'].apply(def())`

Comment: no, it does that for you. It allows you to apply a function to each row (or column) separately without iterating though dataframe manually (=with for loop). Yeah it's like you wrote, but use `axis=1` to make sure it iterate through rows and not columns

Comment: Dear Roim, Thank you for your help !! your suggestion worked like a charm :)